# How to divide AD Departments into equal sized groups using Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have produced a list of AD Departments and produced the number of employees assigned to each department. What I need is to be able to take the list of department counts and break them into groups of equal sizes.

For example if I need a group of 1300 employees than I would run my script and it would cycle through the list of departments and build out the number of groups with any stragglers making up the last group.

What I am trying to avoid is breaking up any 1 department.

The code I am using for my AD Group count is the following:

```
Get-AdUser -LDAPFilter "(&(objectCategory=user)(proxyAddresses=*)(department=*)(title=*)(samaccountname=*)(useraccountcontrol=512)(manager=*))" `
    -Properties * -ResultSetSize $null | group department | Select Name,Count | Sort Count,Name
```

What I am having trouble with is the breaking into groups after the count has been established.

Comment: So, if you have 1000 users in DeptA, 200 in DeptB and 100 in DeptC you'd want 13 groups with 100 users from the same department in each?

Comment: For simplification of this problem yes. However, if I were to elaborate then it would be more along the lines of if I have 10000 users and 10 departments I want to spread 1300 users across an even number of groups, or as close to even as possible, without breaking up the groups if possible.

Comment: iterate thru the collection, assign the index to a var, use that as part of the calculated property to group on with the `Group-Object` cmdlet. something like this >>> `$Index % $NumberOfBatches` <<<